# vue.js connect v-model value, but it would be changeable to other value.

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I connected the second input box for v-model of changedPrice.c1

it is needed to show roundFee as 5000$
but the second input box can get new input numbers.

in this case, what kind of method do I need to use?
computed? @change? can u show me whole answer? Thank you to someone whom help me.

script

```
data() {
    return {
         roundFee : 5000,
         changedPrice: {
             c1: 0,
             c2: 0,
         }
     }
 }
```

vue.js

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled v-model="roundFee"> $
 <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="changedPrice.c1"> $
```

Comment: `v-model` automatically updates the value, but if you want to ensure that it is numeric, you need to use [`v-model.number`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number). You don't need to bind any listeners to it. What do you want to do? Perhaps you can explain it better by rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) as follows:

```
data() {
    return {
         roundFee : 5000,
         changedPrice: {
             c1: 0,
             c2: 0,
         }
     },
     computed: {
         secondInput: {
             get() {
                 return this.roundFee;
             },
             set(newValue) {
                 this.changedPrice.c1 = newValue;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

And then bind this computed property `secondInput` to your input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled v-model="roundFee"> $ 
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="secondInput"> $
```

Comment: it's work, but I'cant modify secondInput inputbox. if I input new thing, it come back to roundFee again